# Find the first repeated word in a string

Tags: php

I need to get the output of the first repeated word from the following

```
$input ="we are the people who are selected by the people of country who gave vote."
```

Desired output `"are"`

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Mind sharing your work with us? We love to help however we're not a code writing service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with [**explode()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and  [**array_count_values()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). `explode()` break down the string to array by a delimiter (here space) and `array_count_values()` count the occurrence of the array elements.

```
$input ="we are the people who are selected by the people of country who gave vote.";
$words = array_count_values(explode(' ', strtolower($input)));

$first_occ = '';
foreach ($words as $word => $count) {
    if ($count > 1) {
        $first_occ = $word;
        break;
    }
}
echo $first_occ;
```

Working **[demo](https://3v4l.org/C1F21)**.

Also can see [**str_word_count**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php).

Comment: str_word_count is good one here